# Using Windows Command Prompt (or PowerShell) to get Disk Drives Listed by Media Type and abbreviated size (GB/TB) as simply as possible

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require a large block of text / code, hopefully only 1 or 2 lines in a .bat script.

So far the main PowerShell call that does these 2 things is the Get-PhysicalDisk, MediaType and Size,

But Size doesn't automatically abbreviate to GB / TB, but I know it or Format Table can, because it does abbreviate to GB / TB if the column it is listed in is restricted in size (width), but I can't figure out a way to force it to?

The standard entry I've used from command prompt is: 
`PowerShell "Get-PhysicalDisk | FT -AutoSize"`

Which gives me something like:

[Output on Command-Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF59G.jpg)

Which looks perfectly fine so long as your HDD / SDDs don't have some insanely long Serial #. In which case you don't even get to see the size.  But the real issue is if you want to customize this so you always see the Size ie: `PowerShell "Get-PhysicalDisk | FT Size, MediaType, FriendlyName, HealthStatus, OperationalStatus -hideTableHeaders -auto"`

Now the size doesn't get summarized in GB, it gets the full number treatment like so:

[Output on Command-Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGXH3.jpg)

So is there a way to format or adjust this simply so it'll list in GB, while also having a listed Media Type? (forgot to add that in the end reminder)  and if it has to be with a script does anyone have a succinct one?

~TY in advance!

An additional Q, using `PowerShell "Get-Disk | FT -auto"`
I get a good abbrev in GB as well, but can't |FT the "Total Size"  since it has a space in it?   or is there a trick to that?

[Output on Command-Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLbj7.jpg)

Comment: cmd: `wmic logicaldisk get name, volumename, size` size is in bytes. ps: `((gdr).Used) + ((gdr).Free)` in bytes

Comment: Then you can divide them by `1073741824`. PS: `$test = (((gdr).Used) + ((gdr).Free))/1073741824` CMD: just use `powrshell -command (((gdr).Used) + ((gdr).Free))/1073741824`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [*Using PowerShell's Calculated Properties*](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx) article e.g. as follows:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk |
    Format-Table -Property @{Name='Size GB'; Expression={$_.Size / 1GB}},
        MediaType, FriendlyName, HealthStatus, OperationalStatus -AutoSize
```

Comment: This works pretty well while keeping the Media Type included, I'll see if I can fiddle with the formatting to make it take up less space, but this'll def get the job done in the meantime!   ~Thank you!